# Select Component exclusively ( InnoSetup )

Tags: inno-setup

Two Components are displayed well with below code.
If I select 'Server' component, then 'Client' component should be unchecked.
If I select 'Client' component, then 'Server' component should be unchecked.

Can you let me know how I can do that?

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\MAEK\bin\MAEK\*.exe";         DestDir: "{app}\bin\"; Flags: ignoreversion ; Components: Server 
Source: "C:\MAEK\bin\MAEK\*.exe";         DestDir: "{app}\bin\"; Flags: ignoreversion ; Components: Client

[Types]
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "Server"; Description: "Server"; Types: custom; 
Name: "Client"; Description: "Client"; Types: custom;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 1 component to choose??

```
[Components]
Name: "Server"; Description: "Server"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
Name: "Client"; Description: "Client"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
```

If more:

```
[Components]
Name: "Mode"; Description: "Installation Mode"; Types: custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "Mode\Server"; Description: "Server"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
Name: "Mode\Client"; Description: "Client"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
```